# How can I achieve cross-process PHP CLI script communication without using the database?

Tags: php, windows-10, interprocess

I'm trying to find an efficient and solid way to "talk" between two CLI PHP scripts. That is, so they can send data to each other, ideally directly sharing an associative array like:

```
echo $_INTERCOM['status message'];
```

I already can implement this using my database, but this has to work when the user has disabled the database features. Besides, it feels like such a waste to use a database, even though (AFAIK) PostgreSQL automatically keeps any table which is small enough in memory, so it won't constantly be reading from the disk.

I have heard of something called "shmop" for PHP, which allegedly enables what I'm asking for. However, I have spent countless hours staring at the manual ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php ) about that without being able to actually use it, so it's way too cryptic for me. I don't understand why it's such a "big deal"; I'm almost certain it must be possible in some built-in, elegant, solid, efficient way.

Comment: you could store data in a file instead. Or use a message queue as an intermediary. Or use direct socket communication between the processes (assuming you can rely on them both being running at the same time, and not disappearing from time to time). it might help if you were clearer about the overall scenario - what do these CLI scripts do? When would they be running? Are they invoked from a user command, or from cron / scheduled tasks, or do they run as daemons / services? Why do they need to share data?